# TypeScript to EcmaScript2015 supported by Node4 using gulp

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, ecmascript-6

I convert TypeScript to ES2015 (because I need async,await), then convert ES2015 to ES2015 supported by Node4 (Node4 not fully compatible with ES2015).

Problem is that TypeScript definition of `express` does not contain `default` field. But this field is actually exists in Javascript code. (actually `express` is just example, problem exists in many other libs `bluebird` for example)

So, If I import `import {default as express} from "express";`, then I have compilation TypeScript error. If I import as `import * as express from "express";`, then I have error when execute `express();` like `express is not a function`in runtime.

Simple project is [here](https://github.com/Lunigorn/ts-babel-integration).

You need type in console:

```
npm install
typings install
gulp clean,build
gulp run
```

to see what I mean. (npm, typescript, gulp should be installed)

How to correct convert TypeScript to ES2015 supported by Node4

Comment: @estus but will I lose typescript compilation type checking when use `require` in typescript?

Comment: @estus I thought `require` used to import JavaScript without type definitions, and no type checking then in typescript.

Comment: But you didn't have type definitions in Node modules any way, did you?

Comment: I think you want [--allowSyntheticDefaultImports](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html) maybe?

Comment: @loganfsmyth but this is not affect on produced code, just type checking, how it will help?

Comment: `import express from "express";` is correct way to import this, and you said that was giving you a typescript error.

Comment: @loganfsmyth this is really works! Thank you! Please, format this comment as answer, and I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `express()` function is conceptually the default of the express package. You'd always want to do

```
import express from "express";

// or this, which is identical, but longer.
import {default as express} from "express";
```

Using a syntax

```
import * as express from "express";
```

will import all of the exports of the module as an object. If you wanted to use that, you'd then have to do

```
express.default();
```

The problem with the first example, as you said, is that it can cause TypeScript to throw a type error. The easiest way to fix this is to tell TypeScript to be a little more flexible with it's expectations around what qualifies as a "default" export, when importing a CommonJS module. This is done by enabling the [--allowSyntheticDefaultImports](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html) option on the TypeScript compiler.

Comment: Do you know how to turn on this option in "Error and syntax highlighting" of Intellij Idea? It thinks that `import express from "express";` is error now and don't give me right "Code completion".

Comment: Hmm, I don't know. Maybe worth a separate question?